# How to change ActionCaching "views/" prefix per request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So we use the same controllers to serve both mobile and desktop views of our site. We also use action caching heavily to cache the html for a page in memcache. I've been trying to figure out a way to globally change the caching prefix for all mobile requests to "views-mobile/" instead of the standard "views/". That way the mobile and and desktop pages will be saved under a different namespace so there are no conflicts in memcache.

We could do this per caches_action method by creating a custom cache_path using the controller variable for is_mobile?, but we'd prefer to do it globally somehow. Any suggestions? I imagine this would require monkey-patching ActionController::Caching but I can't figure out where it generates the "views/" prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up figuring this out myself. Basically ActionController::Base uses a function called fragment_cache_key to generate the cache key for a specific fragment (which is what ActionCaching uses deep down). So you basically override that method and include your own logic for how to generate the prefix. This is how my method override looks:

```
# Monkey patch fragment_cache_key
def fragment_cache_key(key)
    ActiveSupport::Cache.expand_cache_key(key.is_a?(Hash) ? url_for(key).split("://").last : key, mobile_device? ? "views-mobile" : "views")
end
```

Where mobile_device? is my own function that figures out whether the user is requesting the mobile or desktop version of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I was Rails nubie, so I don't really understand about your question, but if it right, is this what you mean?

This is on my **routes.rb**:

```
scope "/administrator" do
   resources :users
end
```

I changed my `users_path` 'prefix' to `administrator`. Sorry if wrong :D